# Is it ok to send response to client inside a executeBlocking() handler?

Tags: java, vert.x

In the vertx route handler below, is it ok to send the response inside the executeBlocking handler?

```
router.route(HttpMethod.POST, "/some-path").handler(context -> {
    vertx.executeBlocking(completePromise -> {
        // Do some time-consuming work
        context.response().end("the response");
    });
```

Or do I have to do it like below, in the original event loop?

```
router.route(HttpMethod.POST, "/some-path").handler(context -> {
    vertx.executeBlocking(completePromise -> {
        // Do some time-consuming work
        completePromise.complete();
    }, resultHandler -> {
        if (resultHandler.succeeded()) {
            context.response().setStatusCode(400).end("failed");
        } else {
            context.response().end("the response");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, although it is a better practice to interact with Vert.x API elements in the original event loop. (for safety and performance).